# contact data transfer mobile to mobile

Tags: data-transfer

How do I transfer my contact details from one mobile to other mobile 
Samsung S3 to Sony Experia P.
I am using both mobiles and want to have contact on both mobiles.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I transfer contacts from one phone to the other without a SIM card?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91722/how-do-i-transfer-contacts-from-one-phone-to-the-other-without-a-sim-card)

Comment: @LieRyan In my opinion the suggested duplicate deals more with transferring the contacts as a one-shot method, whereas this question is more "sync" than "transfer".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Google Contact Sync", an built-in synchronization-mechanism and some of the basic-functionality of android.

More here: http://www.google.com/sync/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to export your contacts (tap the Menu button in the Contacts app then look for Export), transfer Contacts.vcf to the other device, then import.