# How do I transfer contacts from one phone to the other without a SIM card?

Tags: contacts, data-transfer

I have no sim card and a new Android phone. How can I transfer my contacts from one phone to the other without a SIM card?

Comment: if your previous phone has a Bluetooth feature then you can transfer all your contacts through Bluetooth.

Answer (score 7):

No 3rd party utilities or cloud services needed for that. On the "old device":

1. open your contacts app
2. enter its menu
3. select Export/Import
4. select to export to SD card

Now you should find a file named `0001.vcf` on the SD card (internal or external, depends on what the device has). Copy that to the new device, e.g. via Bluetooth, WiFi Hotspot. then, on the new device:

1. open your contacts app
2. enter its menu
3. select Export/Import
4. select to import from SD card
5. chose the file you've just copied here

Done. All your contacts including their contact pictures (if you had set such) should be available on your new device now.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options for your case.

- One option is to sync with Google cloud contacts. In most smartphones, there is a native function to set a contact as a Google contact. *Note: Depending on your phone, you may have to manually make all your contacts sync with Google individually. Some older phones may not support this functionality at all.*
- If you don't want to sync with Google, you can use a third-party app like [Address Book & Contacts Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kylook&hl=en) to (ironically) sync your address book and contacts.
- Depending on your phone, you may be able to sync your contacts with a PC and transfer them, but *this functionality varies from device to device*.

Comment: Some networks do not use SIM cards.

Comment: Right, I was tired when I typed that :p. Gonna edit that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Mobogenie](http://www.mobogenie.com/product/mobogenie-android.html) Software for importing and exporting contacts,sms and any stuff 
on your phone. You can also get backup of your data on your computer.